# Difference between pandas cut() and map()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to understand what the difference is between the .cut() and .map() functions. They both appear to offer ways to categorise or change namings of groups within dataframes and series.

The pandas documentation for .cut() states "This function is also useful for going from a continuous variable to a categorical variable." [Pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) However, you can also do the same thing using .map().

I have tried a little experiment below which basically achieves the same result with both of these - the question is why have 2 functions for the same task?

Creating the dataframe:

```
data1 = {'A':['First','Second','Third'], 'B':[4,5,6] }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1
```

Using the .map()

```
df1['A'] = df1['A'].map({'First': 'Yay', 'Second': 'Ok', 'Third': 'More to Learn'})
df1
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   Yay 4
1   Ok  5
2   More to Learn   6
```

Using the .cut()

```
df1['B'] = pd.cut(df1['B'], 3, labels=['Good', 'Average', 'Terrible'])
df1
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   Yay Good
1   Ok  Average
2   More to Learn   Terrible
```

Comment: I'm not a pandas person, but notice the "continuous variable". In your example, you map stuff to the same number of stuff. But let's see the docs again: "useful for going from a continuous variable to a categorical variable. For example, cut could convert ages to groups of age ranges" - let's categorize all numbers by 10s they have ("I'm in my 20s" etc). If you were to do it manually using map, you'd need to map 20 to 20, 21 to 20... and so on. And what if someone enters partial age? Instead, cut basically does what a chain of ifs like `if 20<=x<=30` would do.

Comment: Does this mean that the .cut function is better when you have a greater number of rows/data. It makes sense that .cut groups and categorises data faster - but then why bother with map at all - or is it just when there is a smaller sample and you want to be more detailed about each value as opposed to grouping larger number of bins?